# CakePHP: How I can increase timeout session?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, timeout, logout

I am trying to set the timeout session to 8 hours in my CakePHP 3.6 application.

I have set in `app.php`:

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout'=>480*60//in minutes
    ],
```

And I can see these values in `phpinfo()` :

```
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly On  Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /app_name/  /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1728000 28800
session.gc_probability  0   0
```

Am I doing something wrong? How I can change timeout so the user is not logged out after ~30 minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to check Session.cookieTimeout value. Although the php session was still valid, the expiration date on the session cookie does not get refreshed

To set it to 8 hours:

```php
    'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timetout' => 60 * 8 // According to documentation this value is in minutes
        'cookieTimeout' => 720, // The session cookie will live for at most 12 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
    ],
```

Comment: well.. again failed, it didn't last for 8 hours. I was logged out after a couple hours of inactivity (didnt check earlier)